# Is the tensor product of a Weil-algebra with a local ring again local?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let me fix a base ring $k$ (which does not need to be a field). A Weil-algebra is a $k$-algebra $W$ equipped with a retraction $\pi:W\to k$ of its structure map $k\to W$ such that the augmentation ideal $I = \operatorname{ker} \pi$ is finite free as a $k$-module ($I= k^n$) and nilpotent.

A Weil-algebra need not be a local ring if $k$ is not a field, but if $k$ is a field then it is local artinian and the augmentation ideal $I$ is the ideal of nilpotents in $W$. Examples of Weil-algebras are $k[x,y]/(x,y)^2$, $k[x]/(x^2)$ and so on.

If $A$ is a $k$-algebra which is local as a ring and $W$ is a Weil-algebra, will $A\otimes_k W$ also be local?

**Edit.** I can do special cases, but I do not know how to attack the problem in general. I do the special case $k[x]/(x^2)$ as an example. A ring $A$ is local if and only if it satisfies

$$\forall x,y:A.\, x+y=1 \to (x \text{ is invertible} \vee y\text{ is invertible})$$

So assume that $A$ is local. $A\otimes_k k[x]/(x^2) = A[x]/(x^2)$. If we have that the sum of two elements $(a + b x) + (c + d x) = 1$, then $a + b = 1$ and $c + d = 0$. Since $A$ is local, we have that $a$ is invertible or $b$ is invertible. Since invertible + nilpotent = invertible, we see that $a + bx$ or $c + dx$ is invertible. This shows that the ring $A[x]/(x^2)$ is local.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Consider the exact sequence $0 \rightarrow I \rightarrow W \rightarrow k\rightarrow 0$ of $k$-modules.

Since $k$ is free (over $k$), it is universally exact: the $-\otimes_k A$ sequence (of $A$-modules) $0 \rightarrow I \otimes_k A \rightarrow W \otimes_k A \rightarrow A \rightarrow 0$ is exact.

Since $I \otimes_k A$ is a finite free $A$-module and is nilpotent in $W \otimes_k A$, the surjective tensor map $W \otimes_k A \rightarrow A$ makes $W \otimes A$ a Weil $A$-algebra. Since its kernel is nilpotent, it induces a homeomorphism $\operatorname{Spec}{A} \rightarrow \operatorname{Spec}(W \otimes_k A)$: in particular, $\operatorname{Spec}{W \otimes_k A}$ has a unique closed point so $W \otimes_k A$ is local.

Comment: How does the tensor map show that $W\otimes_kA$ is a local ring?

Comment: I misread the question (and I’ll edit later) so I had forgotten that part… Anyway, $W \otimes A \rightarrow A$ is onto with nilpotent kernel so is a homeomorphism on spectra – and being a local ring just means “the spectrum contains a unique closed point”.